# remove any child element after certain div index by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

i have this html collection,  i want if i click on any div class ".sday" 
any other div that are **present after** that be remove .

for example if we click on sday 2 we should keep sday1 and sday 2,  and 3 and 4 must delete

my script removing count is ok but it delete wrong div.

any idea?

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div class="room-sheet">
      <div class="sday">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="room-sheet">
      <div class="sday">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="room-sheet">
      <div class="sday">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="room-sheet">
      <div class="sday">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script(using jquery)

```
<script>
  $(".sday").click(function(){
    console.log("hello");

    var parentElement = $(this).parent().parent().find('.room-sheet');
    var parentChildernCount = $(this).parent().parent().find('.room-sheet').length;
     var elementIndex = $(this).closest('.room-sheet').index();

     var dd = parentChildernCount - elementIndex;

     for(let i=elementIndex; i < dd; i++){
                //note: make sure any element after our index in deleted!!!
                $("#parent").find('.room-sheet').children().eq(i).remove();
            }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for clicks on a `.sday` on the parent, navigate to the parent of the clicked `.sday` (a `.room-sheet`), call `nextAll` to get all subsequent siblings, and `.remove()` them:

```js
$('#parent').on('click', '.sday', function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll().remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, there's no need to require a big library like jQuery for something this simple, you may implement this with native DOM methods, if you like:

```js
document.querySelector('#parent').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.sday')) {
    return;
  }
  const sheet = target.parentElement;
  while (sheet.nextSibling) {
    sheet.nextSibling.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="room-sheet">
    <div class="sday">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice explanation +1 for js way

Answer (score 0):

Save the current number and the maximum number in variables then just iterate through them, making sure not to delete the clicked one:

```
$(".sday").on("click", function() {
  let start = parseInt($(this).text());
  let finish = parseInt($(".sday").last().text());
  for (let i = start + 1; i <= finish; i++) {
    $(`.sday:conatins(${i})`).remove();
  }
});
```